# Concatenate two appended values in from two jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the following two lines of code which gives me two values, one in miles and the other in km. i want to concatenate both of them and display in the same column separated by '/'. How will i gain it?

```
@$el.append @odometerColumn2.render().$el
@$el.append @odometerColumn3.render().$el
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `odometerColumn` views contain text nodes, you could do something like:

```
var htmlString = @odometerColumn2.render().$el.text().concat('&#47;', @odometerColumn3.render().$el.text() );
@$el.append(htmlString);
```

If they contain actual HTML you can do the same with `html()` instead of `text()`